# Amazon AWS Static IP & ELB Load Balancing Alternatives

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services

I am currently using `Amazon AWS` to launch a blogging service which offers two different ways to display content to the users

1. Using their own subdomain : `blog.mywebsite.com`
2. Using their own domain : `mywebsite.com`

For version `(1)` I am able to use `CNAMES` which is fine.  For version `(2)` I run into an issue where If I would have a customer point their **mywebsite.com** A Record to my Public IP  **24.x.x.x**  I run into an issue where Amazon by default does not allow  Public IPs to be pointed to loadbalancers.

Has anyone found a work around for this? It's crucial that we have individuals changing their `A records` to the specific IP of the software.

I have considered Apache style load balancing software etc, It just concerns me as it puts a single point of failure for this application.

Comment: What about having the customers use CNAME to point theirdomain.com to elbpublicdns.at.aws.com ?

Comment: My concern is that it would work for **www**.website.com yet if anyone every typed in **http://** website.com it would not resolve.

Comment: CNAME on *.theirdomain.com to your.elb.at.aws.com springs to my mind. I am using these kind of catch-all DNS Records for quite some time now, albeit not with AWS ELB.

Comment: Unfortunately not alot of hosting / dns allows wildcard cname configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the RFC for DNS does not allow CNAMEs for domain roots. There are a few alternatives, whereby you could set up an nginx cluster to do the domain handling for you, or build your own load balancing solution. I know that Route53 (Amazon's DNS service) will allow for forwarding the domain root to an ELB, but getting your customers to use route53 for their dns is prohibitive. Unfortunately at this time there isn't an elegant pure amazon solution for this, but it is a common request, and I know that Amazon is aware of it, and possibly considering a solution for it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin,

It's so unfortunate considering I enjoy AWS interface and their pricing structure. It seems I would have to move it to a different hosting platform just because of this minor..yet critical issue.